# UTF-8: showing correct in database, but not in webpage

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, encoding, utf-8

When i upload data from php post forums  "**हिन्दी**" language, changed into "**à¤¹à¤°à¤¿à**" in database but looking correct in webpage,

and

when i upload data through phpmyAdmin from csv file "**हिन्दी**" changed into "**???????**" in webpage but looking correct in mysql database,

i ran a query,

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%char%'
```

output results:

```
+------------------------------+-------+--+----+--+----+--+---
|        Variable_name         |        Value                |  
+------------------------------+-------+--+----+--+----+--+---
| character_set_client         |        utf8mb4              |

| character_set_connection     |        utf8mb4              |  
|                              |                             |  
| character_set_database       |        utf8mb4              |  
|                                 
| character_set_filesystem     |        binary               |  
|                              |                             |
| character_set_results        |        utf8mb4              |  
|                              |                             |
| character_set_server         |        latin1               |

| character_set_system         |        utf8                 |
|                         
| character_sets_dir           | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/  |  
|   +------------------------------+-------+--+----+--+----+--
```

is everything ok?

i have thousands of data, so i don't want to upload from post forums one bye one.
how to get correct this, to get expected results?

MySQL version 5.6.37

Answer (score 0):

Two different errors "Mojibake" and "Question marks".  Both are discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

You have the equivalent of `SET NAMES utf8mb4`, but that is only one thing.  Are the bytes in the csv file really UTF-8?  Are the column(s) defined as `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`?  Does the `<form...>` indicate utf8 is expected?  Etc.  (See that link.)

Dump the hex from the table; it should be `E0A4B9 E0A4BF E0A4A8 E0A58D E0A4A6 E0A580` for those letters and signs.  `C3A0 C2A4 ...` would indicate "double encoding".  I point out the hex because your statement 'changed into "à¤¹à¤°à¤¿à" in database but looking correct in webpage' could be caused by either Mojibake or double encoding -- depending on whether the coding problem is with inserting or with selecting.

Note:  `CHARACTER SET utf8` and `ut8mb4` are both adequate for Devangari and other Indian languages.  It is better to stick with utf8mb4 in case you ever need Emoji or Chinese.

Comment: bytes in the csv file is UTF-8,columns defined as CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,table defined as CHARACTER SET utf8mb4

Comment: And the settings for phpmyadmin?

Comment: And the `<meta ...` in the html?

Comment: And the hex of the data in the table?

Comment: yes i have a meta tag, `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in my html,

Comment: can you please tell me command for dump out hex?

Comment: `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM tbl WHERE ...`  Only need to see a few characters of one row.

Comment: hex dump=C3A0C2A4C2B9C3A0C2A4C2B0C3A0C2A4C2BFC3A0C2A4C2AFC3...

  string showing in database=à¤¹à¤°à¤¿à¤¯à¤¾à¤£à¤¾ à¤°à¤¾à¤œà¥à¤¯ à¤•à¥€ à¤¸à¥€à¤®à¤¾à¤‚ à¤•à¤¿à¤¤à¤¨à¥‡ à¤°à¤¾à¤œà¥à¤¯à¥‹à¤‚ à¤¸à¥‡ à¤²à¤—à¤¤à¥€ à¤¹à¥ˆà¤‚ ?

Comment: "Double encoding".  That probably happened when `INSERTing` utf8 bytes while connected as `latin1`.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases

Comment: (Or you could reload the data -- with the connection corrected.  Just make sure the HEX ends up correct in the table.)

Comment: solved, https://stackoverflow.com/a/4779380/4645254, i added `mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");` after connection connect,

Comment: @PraveenYadav - But... Your `SHOW VARIABLES ...` implies that you had done the effect of the `SET NAMES` ??

Comment: @RickJemes i added `mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");` in config.php file after database connect,

Comment: @PraveenYadav - Caution:  `root` ignores `init_connect`.

Comment: i don't know much about these things, but now my database and website working good.